# Python (Jython) - can I access variable names in property setter and getter functions?

Tags: python, jython, python-2.5, jython-2.5

I have the following class. The behavior for `self.value` and `self.name` are identical. Only the variable names are different. How can I rewrite this so that I don't have to define two essentially identical property definitions just because I'm working with different variable names? Can I access the variable names in the setter and getter functions and maybe use `getattr()` and `setattr()`?

I'm using: Jython 2.5.2

```
class StateMachineState(object):
def __init__(self, value, name):
    self.valueHash = None
    self.nameHash = None
    self.stateHash = None
    self.value = value
    self.name = name

def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.stateHash == other.stateHash if self.__class__ == other.__class__ else False

def __str__(self):
    return "value = %s (%s) - name = %s (%s) - (%s)" % (self.value, self.valueHash, self.name, self.nameHash, self.stateHash)

def getValue(self):
    return self._value

def setValue(self, value):
    try:
        str(value)
        hash(value)
        self.valueHash = hash(str(value) + str(value.__class__))
        self._value = value
    except:
        self.valueHash = None
        self._value = None
    self.stateHash = hash(str(self.valueHash) + str(self.nameHash))

def getName(self):
    return self._name

def setName(self, name):
    try:
        str(name)
        hash(name)
        self.nameHash = hash(str(name) + str(name.__class__))
        self._name = name
    except:
        self.nameHash = None
        self._name = None
    self.stateHash = hash(str(self.valueHash) + str(self.nameHash))

value = property(getValue, setValue)
name = property(getName, setName)
```

Comment: Why do you even *have* all this weird machinery? Why not just use two normal `value` and `name` attributes and compute `__hash__` as `hash((self.value, self.name))`? Why are you computing `__eq__` based on hash values when hashes can collide? Why do your setters silence all errors? You're just creating problems for yourself.

Comment: Because I have different sources that will use this same class. Each source may use different data types (classes) for value and name. As long as they can be coerced into type str and are hashable the source can use whatever value and name type they want. What do you mean the hashes can collide? The setters will have some kind of error reporting. I just haven't put that in here because it has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: None of what you just said is a reason to have all this weird machinery. As for hash collision, two objects that shouldn't be considered equal may easily produce the same hash value.

Comment: The hash value of an object is unique within it's class. I hash the `value` and `name` values and include the str() value of the class to guarantee a unique hash value. I have all this wired machinery because to compare equal states I will use the stateHash value. To search for states with matching values or names I will search using valueHash and nameHash values. I appreciate your input but instead of trying to understand and correct my design please contribute an answer to my actual question... which I was able to solve myself.

Comment: "The hash value of an object is unique within it's class" - first, [no, hash values are not unique, even within a class](https://ideone.com/zJIKIy). Second, even if you're using classes where the hash values *are* guaranteed to be unique, the second layer of hashing with `str` values could still cause a collision.

Comment: "The hash value of an object is unique within it's class" - you're right, this is inaccurate. I stand corrected on this one. I assumed this since dictionaries use hash on the keys and since the keys all need to be unique then I assumed the hash would be unique. Then if the hash doesn't guarantee uniqueness then how can it be used as it is with dictionaries?

Comment: The hash values are used to accelerate the lookup process, but the dict still needs to compare the provided key against the one in the dict with `==` to verify that it's a real match and not a collision.

Comment: `StateMachineState({"a":1}, None) == StateMachineState({"b":2}, None)` is true, I think that is what @iamthebull was getting at, that using unhashable values gives instances the same hash value of `None` which is not unique.

Comment: Does anyone have any feedback on the actual question about property functions?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem using a wrapper function:

```
class StateMachineState(object):
    def __init__(self, value, name):
        self.valueHash = None
        self.nameHash = None
        self.stateHash = None
        self.value = value
        self.name = name

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.stateHash == other.stateHash if self.__class__ == other.__class__ else False

    def __str__(self):
        return "( %s (%s) , '%s' (%s) ) - (%s)" % (self.value, self.valueHash, self.name, self.nameHash, self.stateHash)

    def getAttrValue(self, attrName):
        return getattr(self, '_' + attrName)

    def setAttrValue(self, attrName, value):
        valueName = '_%s' % attrName
        hashName = '%sHash' % attrName
        try:
            str(value)
            hash(value)
            setattr(self, hashName, hash(str(value) + str(value.__class__)))
            setattr(self, valueName, value)
        except:
            setattr(self, hashName, None)
            setattr(self, valueName, None)
        self.stateHash = hash((self.valueHash, self.nameHash))

    def getValue(self):
        return self.getAttrValue('value')

    def setValue(self, value):
        self.setAttrValue('value', value)

    def getName(self):
        return self.getAttrValue('name')

    def setName(self, name):
        self.setAttrValue('name', name)

value = property(getValue, setValue)
name = property(getName, setName)
```